# Concatenate error: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, sequential

I'm working on a snippet in Keras where I have two Sequential models that needs to be merged in a third one which is my final model. The snippet was build with a version of Keras where Merge method was allowed, so now I'm trying to replace it with concatenate method with `axis = 0` so the behavior is the same as Merge(). Despite all of this modifies, I receive the following stacktrace as output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\CaptionGenerator.py", line 738, in <module>
    caption.BeamPredictor('image.PNG')
  File ".\CaptionGenerator.py", line 485, in BeamPredictor
    self.SetNeuralNetworksWithoutApi()
  File ".\CaptionGenerator.py", line 433, in SetNeuralNetworksWithoutApi
    Activation('softmax')
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.add(layer)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 131, in add
    'Found: ' + str(layer))
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_1/concat:0", shape=(?, 40, 300), dtype=float32)
```

The snippet code is:

```
def SetNeuralNetworksWithoutApi(self):

    embedding_size = 300

    image_model = Sequential([
    Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
    RepeatVector(self.MaxCaptionLength)
    ])

    caption_model = Sequential([
    Embedding(self.numberOfWords, embedding_size, input_length=self.MaxCaptionLength),
    LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
    TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
    ])

    image_in = Input(shape=(2048,))
    caption_in = Input(shape=(self.numberOfWords,))
    merged = concatenate([image_model(image_in), caption_model(caption_in)])
    latent = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))(merged)
    out = Dense(self.numberOfWords, activation='softmax')(latent)
    self.softmaxModel = Model([image_in, caption_in], out)

    self.softmaxModel.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(), metrics=['accuracy'])
    self.softmaxModel.summary()
```

I cannot understand the reason why the result of my concatenate() should not be an instance of Layer class, considering that there is not a layer property in the object returned from the function which, according to the Documentation, is a Tensor. Is there any way to fix this without switching to API? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch to the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) at least for the final model because `Sequential` is designed to have a *single* input, you are forcing 2 tensors into it, which is not going to work. This is because Sequential creates a single placeholder for its input. Something along the lines of:

```
image_model = Sequential([
Dense(embedding_size, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
RepeatVector(self.MaxCaptionLength)
])

caption_model = Sequential([
Embedding(self.numberOfWords, embedding_size, input_length=self.MaxCaptionLength),
LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
TimeDistributed(Dense(300))
])

image_in = Input(shape=(2048,))
caption_in = Input(shape=(MaxCaptionLength, numberOfWords))
merged = concatenate([image_model(image_in), caption_model(caption_in)], axis=0)
latent = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False))(merged)
out = Dense(self.numberOfWords, activation='softmax')(latent)
final_model = Model([image_in, caption_in], out)

final_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(), metrics=['accuracy'])
final_model.summary()
```

You can still keep image and caption models separate but even if there is a workaround to connect Sequential with 2 inputs, I wouldn't recommend it as it is not the intended use of the API.

Comment: don't you mean out=Dense(self.numberOfWords, activation="softmax")(latent) instead of out?